# Error:(44, 0) Version: 4.0.4 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I am trying to add the firebase admin SDK to my project following the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

but when i add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.0.4'` on my build.grandle file, then following error appears:

```
Error:(44, 0) Version: 4.0.4 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.
```

If i try version 4.0.3  i face the same problem.

My build.grandle file at the moment:

```
android {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.qrcodereader"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.0.4'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to install the admin SDK on a mobile device? You should be using the [client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) here. The admin SDK is intended for server processes.

Comment: Hi Kato, thank you very much, 
I was confused but now i understood the difference. Thanks again